# Make PHP zipArchive slower

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm currently using zipArchive in a simple PHP script to dynamically group files before download.
My script is based on this very simple peace of code.

```
$zip = new zipArchive();
if ($zip->open($destinationFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true)
    die('Error...');

foreach($documents as $docName => $docURI)
    $zip->addFile($docURI, $docName);
```

The code works fine. My problem is more due to the resources usage, and especially to disc IO.
The website is hosted on shared servers, thus I've a very limited possibilities.

When script is running it uses full IO quota (1.5MB/s). It result that my website is crazy slow. Sometimes we need more than 10s to load a very small page...

I would like to limit the disk usage of the script to keep the website usable and quite responsive.

If I've a lot of very small files to add to archive I can simple add a sleep into the loop.
However, it is not a solution when I've to add larger files.

I didn't manage to find a way to force it to run slower.
I don't know them, but streams may possibly help me by treating large file in separated chunks.
However, streams are read-only in zipArchive. Streams was also great to reduce memory usage.

I think that it is not a common query...

Comment: Since ZipArchive is a built-in class, I don't think there's a way to sanely do this. You might want to consider switching to non-shared servers.

Comment: Obviously, by switching to a dedicated server, I could make a background stand-alone script and put several constraints on it to limit all I need.
However, it is not possible for now.
I know that zipArchive is not that I need.. I took a look to zlib and filters but it is not made for zip file creation. Maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: Well, of course you can hack at a pure-PHP library such as (first Google result) https://github.com/Ne-Lexa/php-zip to add delays...

Comment: May you could change process priority to lower using for example that function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-setpriority.php ?